# Can't find, delete, rename or recreate table in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm recently trying to get into MySQL and have been setting up a test database on my localhost with a set of CSV files. I most recently was trying to change the data type of one of the columns of the tables to the date format (it was originally in an int format, eg '20140321'), but when I tried to process the request, the MySQL part of XAMPP crashed.

Now, when I go in to look at my tables, the table that I was working on will no longer show up in the database. However, when I try to reimport the data and name it with the same name, there appears to be a naming conflict, as if the original file is still there.

Is there a way to find the original table and get it back up and running in PHPMyAdmin? Or if not, is there a way to clear out the records of the old table and just restart?

When I try to just rename the newly imported table, I get this error (which doesn't seem very helpful):

```
Error
SQL query:

RENAME TABLE `mta`.`TABLE 9`
                  TO `mta`.`calendar_dates`;
MySQL said: Documentation

#1025 - Error on rename of '.\mta\table@00209' to '.\mta\calendar_dates' (errno: -1 - Unknown error)
```

When I delete the `table.ibd` file in my `C:\xampp\mysql\data\db\` manually, and try to rename the table, I get an error with duplicate foreign keys I'd set up for the original table. (I also notice that each of the other tables has an associated .frm file which this one doesn't anymore).

I'd imagine there's a fairly easy way to get the table back into the database, but I'm currently at a loss on where I should be looking to do it.

Answer (score 2):

i have this problem in the past, This Is A problem in Previous Version Of Xampp.
update xampp to latest version until resolve this problem in phpmyadmin